# Why can't I see my background on div

Tags: html

I have one container and I have float:left inside it's child div. Problem is as soon as I apply float:left on child div my parent div's background is completely lost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="background: #CCC; width:100%; position:relative;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                This is some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody tell me how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float` elements do not have `height` unless you clear them below or give explicit `height`

Try this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="background: #CCC; width:100%; height:50px;position:relative;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                This is some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

OR

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background: #CCC; width:100%; position:relative;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                This is some text
            </div>
            <div style='clear:left'></div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

OR use this hack of setting `overflow` of element.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background: #CCC; width:100%; overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                This is some text
            </div> 
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you beat me to it...

Your inner (nested) `div` is floated, so your outer `div` is collapsing. You have a few options:

1. Put an empty `clear` div inside the floated div
2. Apply a `overflow:hidden` style to the outer div
3. remove the inner div, and float the outer div