# Background of div is not going with content

Tags: css, html

I am new to html and css. I coded a html page with css but confused.

I used this css code

```
#container {
background: #000000;
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
}
#left {
background: #FF0000;
width: 200px;
float: left;
}
#right {
background: #0000FF;
width: 200px;
float: right;
}
```

and this html code

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left">This is left</div>
<div id="right">This is right</div>
</div>
```

But I didn't got black background that I specified in #container.
Can you help me with that. I want background to move automatically as i write content. in between divs having id container.

Comment: try, overflow:auto on #container

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I see my background on div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760838/why-cant-i-see-my-background-on-div)

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using Float for your inner divs and the container does not contain any text,

try this

```
<div id="container">


    hello <br>
<div id="left">This is left</div>
<div id="right">This is right</div>
<br><br>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `#container` to

```
float: left;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyaeT/) for live example.

Answer (score 0):

This will works fine for you

```
#container {border:2px solid #cccccc;
height:50px;
background-color: #000000;
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
}
```